# how to build the code for running rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, markers.rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials for Markers :sending basic shapes.
I am stuck at this step, where it says build the code using command
cd %TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WORKSPACE%
catkin_make

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279646/how-to-build-the-code-for-running-rviz?/) by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-12**:
Please state more clearly what your Problem is.
Don't you understand what this means or is there a Problem with the build?

**Comment by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on 2018-01-12**:
My workspace is catkin_ws
I use two commands
**cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make**
After that I use
**rosrun using_markers basic _shapes**
where using_markers is package name and i want to run basic_shapes. But I am getting error,
**[WARN] Please create a subscriber to the marker**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This part of the tutorial means you need to use a terminal to navigate to the top level directory of your workspace then run **catkin_make**

For example if you have a workspace directory called **my_project_ws** inside your home directory you can open a terminal and type the following command to move to the workspace.

```
cd ~/my_project_ws
```

If you type the `ls` command (short for list) it will show the contents of this directory which should contain a **src** directory and possibly some other directories and files. Now you're in the right location you can build your package by typing:

```
catkin_make
```

Hope this clears this up for you.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on 2018-01-12**:
My workspace is catkin_ws
I use two commands
**cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make**
After that I use
**rosrun using_markers basic _shapes**
where using_markers is package name and i want to run basic_shapes. But I am getting error,
**[WARN] Please create a subscriber to the marker**
Please help with this error

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-13**:
Okay you've got the build working that's great. To keep these answers tidy can you please accept this answer and ask a new question for the warning you've just described. It gets confusing if more than one question get asked and answered in a single thread. Thanks.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-13**:
Looking at the source code of the node. The message **[WARN] Please create a subscriber to the marker** isn't an error at all it's what the node is meant to do. try starting **RVIZ** and viewing the topic, that should show everything working.